# ArcGIS python 2.5  script - create a stats table  by iterating the recordset

Tags: python

I need to iterate  the fields and compute sum of few columns group by the value in another column .

For ex base table is

```
C1 C2 C3 C4  C5
a1  2  3  4  q
a1  4  5  7  a
a2 34 56  6  e
a2  4  5  5  5
a3  3  3  3  4
a3  3  3  3  3
```

The result table should be

```
   c2 c3 c4
a1  6  8 11
a2 38 61 11
a3  6  6  6
   50 75 28
```

I am able to iterate the fields to get the value of each field but got stuck in creating a two dimension matrix of result format. I was looking into 2 dimension array to achieve this scenario.

Comment: are your columns always sorted?

Comment: Are `C1-5` and `a1-3` part of the actual data, or are they just here for clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Working from a lot of assumptions here since the question is quite unspecific...

```
# table containing only the actual data
table = [[2,3,4,"q"],[4,5,7,"a"],[34,56,6,"e"],[4,5,5,5],[3,3,3,4],[3,3,3,3]]
result = []

# iterate through table[0/2/4/...] zipped together with table[1/3/5/...]
for (row1, row2) in zip(table[::2], table[1::2]):
    # add the first three elements of each row and append the results to our result
    result.append([c1+c2 for c1,c2 in zip(row1[:3], row2[:3])])

print(result)
```

outputs

```
[[6, 8, 11], [38, 61, 11], [6, 6, 6]]
```